# How to find multiple substrings of a string, but if multiple are not found, still return however many substrings were found

Tags: php

Ok, its easier to explain like this.

I have a variable:

```
 $string
```

I also have have substring variables:

```
$sub1, $sub2, $sub3, $sub4
```

I need to echo $string if any of the substring variables are found. Including if multiple substring variables are found.

I am using this to find substrings:

```
    if (strpos($filename, $clothes) > 0 {
        echo $string
    }
```

The thing thats confusing me mostly is returning $string if there are all OR just some of the substrings.

Comment: I don't clearly understand you. What is `$filename` and `$clothes` in your example?

Comment: Do you need to return the string or just echo it? Your question is not clear.

Comment: Are you trying to string 'OR' statements?  Also, `strpos` might return 0 if the string begins at the first letter. Making your statement return `false` even if it is `true`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First, for sake of simplicity, consider those substring variables as an array.
Now, the code may look like this,

```
function doIt($string, $sub_strings){
    foreach($sub_strings as $substr){
        if(strpos($string, $substr) !== FALSE)
        {
          return $string; // at least one of the needle strings are substring of heystack, $string
        }
    }

   return ""; // no sub_strings is substring of $string.
}
```

and to use this function,

```
echo doIt($string,array($str1,$str2,$str3,$str4));
```

Thanks to Orangepill!

Comment: +1 I like your approach ... just `echo doId($string, $subs);`

Comment: I've run into an issue. What my program is actually doing is looping though lots of different $strings .

Answer (score 0):

Just create a function that tests each value in an array against the string and return true if any are found.

```
function findOneOf(array $terms, $string){
      foreach ($terms as $term){
          if (strpos($string, $term) !== FALSE){
              return true;
          }
      }
      return false;
}
```

Then you can do your test like

```
if (findOneOf(array($sub1, $sub2, $sub3,$sub4), $string)){
     echo $string;
}
```